# Why userdefined move constructor is not called in below example?

Tags: c++, oop, constructor

I am expecting that after using std::move(any_object) we are converting that object in rvalue reference and due to this it should call my userdefined move constructor. but it is not working like this.Could anyone tell whats happening?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct Demo {
    int Value;
    Demo():Value(10) { std::cout << "Demo's default constructor called\n";}
    Demo(Demo& tempObj) { std::cout << "Demo non-const copy constructor called\n";}
    Demo(const Demo& tempObj) { std::cout << "Demo const copy constructor called\n"; }
    Demo(Demo&& tempObj) { std::cout << "Demo move constructor called\n"; }
    Demo(const Demo&& tempObj) { std::cout << "Demo const move constructor called\n"; }
    Demo& operator= (const Demo& tempObj){ std::cout << "Demo copy assignment operator called ";}
    Demo& operator= (Demo&& tempObj){ std::cout << "Demo move assignment operator called";}
    ~Demo(){ std::cout << "Demo's destructor called\n";}
};

void fun(Demo&& tempObj)
{
    tempObj.Value = 20;
}

int main()
{
    Demo demo;
    fun(std::move(demo));
}
```

//output:

```
Demo's default constructor called
Demo's destructor called
```

Comment: You're not actually constructing a new `Demo` object using the rvalue reference. If `fun` took its argument by value, you would see the move constructor being used. By default `std::move` doesn't create a new object. It just tells the compiler which overload resolution to use. Sometimes that implies using a move constructor, but not in this case because no constructor at all is required.

Comment: Also, you're missing return statement inside assignment operators.

Comment: Try `Demo demo2{std::move(demo)};`

Comment: Worth pointing out that the move constructor is not marked as `noexcept`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why userdefined move constructor is not called in below example?

Because you're only **binding** an *rvalue reference* to an `xvalue` and **not** actually constructing an instance of type `Demo`. That is, a move constructor will be called when you actually construct an instance of type `Demo` using a rvalue as shown below for example:

```
//-----------v-------->removed && from here
void fun(Demo tempObj)
{
    tempObj.Value = 20;
}
fun(std::move(demo)); //now this uses move constructor
```

---

Additionally, you missing return statement in your assignement operators.